# How to move files based on characters left to the file extension to a subfolder?

Tags: batch-file

Since I do not have a lot of experience in coding batch files, I would like to ask for some helping hands.

There are multiple files in the source folder. The files list is like this.

```
ABCD_CH_DEFGH.XLS
ABCD_CH_DEFGH.PDF
ABCD_CH_DEFGH_001_001.XLS
ABCD_CH_DEFGH_001_001.PDF
QWER_DE_OPESADHXCS_002_002.XLS
QWER_DE_OPESADHXCS_002_002.PDF
```

I would need a batch file which iterates through the files in the source folder and moves only files with the substring `_xxx_xxx.` to an existing subfolder which are in this case:

```
ABCD_CH_DEFGH_001_001.XLS
ABCD_CH_DEFGH_001_001.PDF
QWER_DE_OPESADHXCS_002_002.XLS
QWER_DE_OPESADHXCS_002_002.PDF
```

Comment: move "*_xxx_xxx.*" subfoldername

Comment: Sorry, I havn't been precise enough, only files with a numerical pattern ( e.g. _002_002. ), left to the file extension should be moved, but not files like "_unw_phy."

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%i in ('"dir *.pdf | findstr /RIC:"_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf""') do move "%%~i" "Subfolder\"`

Comment: After fiddling around with the command, finally I got it to work                                                                           for /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%i in ('"dir *.pdf | findstr /RIC:"_[0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9].pdf""') do move "%%~i" "Subfolder\"